# Facebook Profile Photo disappears after reloading view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, fbsdk

I'm grabbing a user's Facebook profile photo for an app I'm making, and loading it on their settings page above their name.  When I load the photo, I'm using this code:

```
func getProfilePic(){
    let params: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["redirect": false, "height": 400, "width": 400, "type": "small"]
    let pictureRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "GET")
    pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("\(result)")


            let dictionary = result as? NSDictionary
            let data = dictionary?.objectForKey("data")
            let urlPic = (data?.objectForKey("url"))! as! String
            print(urlPic)

            let url = NSURL(string: urlPic)
            let data2 = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)
            if data2 != nil {
                self.photo = UIImage(data:data2!)!
            }
        } else {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

It works great the first time I load the view in Simulator.  However if I navigate to my menu, which uses the code below, then navigate back, the photo has disappeared from its UIImage View.

Navigating to an overlay menu:

```
@IBAction func navToMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userMainMenu")
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 112/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 0.9)
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Navigating back to settings view from overlaid menu:

```
@IBAction func navToSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("navToUserSettings", sender: self)
}
```

So to clarify one last time:

Load the View -> Picture Appears -> Activate Overlaid Menu View, Dismiss Overlaid Menu View -> Picture has Disappeared

Has anyone experienced a similar problem, or have a solution to what I'm experiencing in my project?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are executing the graph request every time that view loads.  You should be storing the results from this graph somewhere and then populating your UI based on those results.  When you navigate away from your view you lose your reference to the image. Try printing the url of your picture and see if that has a value when you navigate back to your view

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm planning on implementing CoreData into my project soon and storing some more long-term data, and this is definitely what I'm planning on doing with the Facebook photos.